# Magento 2.2.6 quick search is not working for sometimes

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, search, search-terms

I am trying to search a product through a quick search using the product name and its brand name.

But it does not work for all product. Only for some product.

E.g if I search products of brand "XYZ" then it shows the result. But when I search products of brand "ABC" it shows me a message **"Your search returned no results."**

I have checked at Marketing >> SEO & Search >> Search terms

So it shows the result count 0 for that particular term.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I have cleared the cache properly and done re-indexing also

Comment: do you have any resolution to your question?